# Benefits multiple instances tomcat one server

Tags: tomcat

We have 1 physical servers, are there any advantages of running multiple instances of Tomcat on one box or doesn't it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing resources would be the major selling point here.

Multiple tomcat instances allow to share common binaries and underlying OS resources.
If you want more isolation, RHEL 7's LXC support might be a start.

I recommend multiinstance usually if the box has enough resources to host multiple java applications and they need different settings/or a different JDK, but the same tomcat version.

Keep in mind though that you have to focus more on security in this setup.

Comment: but in one 1 physical servers multiple instances of Tomcat improves the performance or not? or only if you have many physical servers?

Comment: If the server can handle multiple instances to shoulder their load plus a little headroom, you don't need to buy multiple servers, that's the point. Multiple tomcat instances on one box are not likely to increase performance.

Comment: then multiple instances on a single server to serve only be able to use all possible resources?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope that helps. Find me in the chatroom if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat containers share resources in surprising ways.  So, if you try to run multiple servlets inside one instance of tomcat, be aware that even though the configuration may make it appear that they are listening on different ports or IPs, or have different certificates or client certificate requirements, it's usually possible to access one on another's connector by specifying the servlet name as part of the URI.  If you run them in the same instance you also open up the possibility that a JRE bug might be used to break isolation.

You can run multiple tomcat instances on one host, but you should really consider running each inside a VM.  This is slightly more resource-intensive but vastly more maintainable and secure.